# Украшение сайта

Tags: jquery, javascript, css

Привет всем! Кто подскажет красивые бесплатные скрипты на веб-языках. Может это эффект написан на jQuery. Но желательно мало нагрузки на сервер и нужное. К примеру, увеличение картинки + затемнение.

**Доп. информация:** У меня бесплатный локальный торрент трекер без подключения к интернету.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Лайтбокс](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/#example) - пользуюсь им. А вообще, сильно загружать сайт не надо (я имею ввиду снежинки и проч.). Как правило, доп. эффекты будут требоваться уже в процессе разработки (я сейчас говорю про работу без ТЗ). Лучше напишите списком, что вам требуется, а я подгоню ссылок.

Спойлер.

js(jquery):

```
$('.sp_title').bind('click',function(){$('.sp_content').slideUp(100);$('.sp_title').removeClass('active');var thig=$(this).next('.sp_content');if(thig.css('display')=='none'){thig.slideDown(100);$(this).addClass('active');}else{thig.slideUp(100);$(this).removeClass('active');}});
```

html:

```
<div class="sp_title">title</div>
<div class="sp_content">content</div>
```

Comment: Я полностью согласен с Вами. Мне хотелось какие-то эффекты, к примеру, может есть спойлер плавный, но легкий к верстке. Или, например, маленькие, нужные на ваше мнение скрипты.
Лайтбокс - вкурсе, но пользуюсь colorbox.

Comment: Спойлер легче некуда. )

Comment: А что-то есть из хороших скриптов?

Comment: Опять же, всё зависит от ваших потребностей.

Answer (score 0):

Подсказываю: jQuery + [плагины](http://plugins.jquery.com/). При правильном подключении скриптов все летает, при неправильном - ничего не работает. Нагрузки на сервер никакой, так как javascript - клиентская технология.
По поводу лайтбокса, сам пользуюсь [prettyPhoto](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-lightbox-clone-prettyPhoto). Доволен как слон.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри вот этот сайт [jqueryui.com](http://jqueryui.com/), тут много различных интерфейсных плагинов для jQuery.

PS: [Тут](http://anton.shevchuk.name/javascript/jquery-for-beginners/) можно почитать полезную информацию (на русском) про сам jQuery, кстати и примеры всяческие там есть с разъяснениями.